# Lambda member function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am trying to create a functional field in a class, that can be set by a user to arbitrary lambda function, and then invoked as if it was a member function. The field is basically an `std::function`, but should implicitly pass `this` as its first parameter when its `operator()` is invoked.

Suppose that the `Event` class does what I want to achieve:

```
template <typename... Args> class Event;
```

then I want to be able to write:

```
class Container {
public:
    Event<int> func = this ;
};

int main() {
     Container c;
     c.func = [](Container* This, int x) {
         .......
     };
     c.func(42);
     return 0;
}
```

I would like to be able to assign other function-like objects (e.g. structs with `operator()`) as it is the case with `std::function`.

I thought that if I implement `Event` as a derivative of `std::function`, and import its `operator=` definitions, it would work. But there seems to be some ambiguity.

This is what I have written:

```
#include <functional>

class Container;

template <typename... Args>
class Event : public std::function<void(Container*, Args...)> {
private:
    typedef std::function<void(Container*, Args...)> ParentType;
    Container* This;
public:
    using ParentType::operator=;

    Event(Container* This) : This(This) {}
    void operator()(Args... args) {
        ParentType::operator()(This, args...);
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, I get some warnings and errors when trying to compile it:

```
event.h(17): warning C4522: 'Event<int>' : multiple assignment operators specified
1>          container.h(6) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Event<int>' being compiled
1>main.cpp(19): error C2666: 'std::function<void (Container *,int)>::operator =' : 3 overloads have similar conversions
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(632): could be 'std::function<void (Container *,int)> &std::function<void (Container *,int)>::operator =(const std::function<void (Container *,int)> &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(642): or       'std::function<void (Container *,int)> &std::function<void (Container *,int)>::operator =(std::function<void (Container *,int)> &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(674): or       'std::function<void (Container *,int)> &std::function<void (Container *,int)>::operator =(std::function<void (Container *,int)> &&)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(700): or       'std::function<void (Container *,int)> &std::function<void (Container *,int)>::operator =(std::nullptr_t)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(685): or       'std::function<void (Container *,int)> &std::function<void (Container *,int)>::operator =<main::<lambda_744a2f58777db28ba36902fcfe375a8a>>(_Fx &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fx=main::<lambda_744a2f58777db28ba36902fcfe375a8a>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(Event<int>, main::<lambda_744a2f58777db28ba36902fcfe375a8a>)'
```

... and I am getting lost.
Should I "import" only one of the inherited `operator=`? Implement my own and somehow call one of them?

Comment: The error message almost looks like a compiler bug to me. Did you try writing your own assignment operator template and forwarding to `std::function`'s? (Also I wouldn't use `public` inheritance here, since that allows overriding the private `Container*` member for function calls by casting to the `std::function` base.)

Comment: You are right that it may be yet another problem of Visual Studio. It compiles just fine with clang++ ang g++.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the parent `operator=` is a terrible idea for polymorphic objects.  Remember, `function` is polymorphic.  In general I think you should prefer aggregation over derivation, because then you have much better control over what gets called and when, like this:

```
template <typename... Args>
class Event  {
public:
    typedef std::function<void( Container*, Args... )> ParentType;
    ParentType inner;
    Container* This;

    Event( Container* This ) : This( This ) {}
    void operator()( Args... args ) {
        inner( This, args... );
    }
};

int main() {
    Container c;
    c.func.inner = []( Container* This, int x ) {
    };
    c.func( 42 );
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, if you don't want to expose the internals of `Event` publicly you can make them private and supply appropriate setter functions.